# Shell - syntax error in expression (error token is "0 ")

Tags: bash, shell, testing

What is wrong with this code?

```
if  (( `date +%U` % 2 -eq 0 ))
then
   VOLUME= "A"
else
    VOLUME="B"
fi
```

I´m getting "syntax error in expression (error token is "0 ")" eror.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use command substitution using `$(...)` syntax.

You can use this command:

```
(( $(date +%U) % 2 == 0 )) && VOLUME="A" || VOLUME="B"
```

Comment: I would not recommend the use of `… && … || …` in this case

Comment: `foo && bar || baz` is not equivalent to `if foo; then bar; else baz; fi`, See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cmd1_.26.26_cmd2_.7C.7C_cmd3

Comment: Yes that I know but that still doesn't explain the reason of not using it in OP's case. (assigning a variable)

Comment: just a didactic/pedagogic question. Could lead to some wrong usage, at least add the lead to the pitfall page so people can learn how to use this construct

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is the use of `-eq` operator in the context of an arithmetic test (the double parenthesis).

You need [Command Substitution `$(…)`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution):

```
if (( $(date +%U) % 2 == 0 )); then VOLUME= "A" else VOLUME="B"; fi
```

N.B.: [Why is `$(…)` preferred over `` `…` `` (backticks)?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082)

Comment: The use of backticks rather than `$(...)` is not a problem, though `$(...)` is probably better if you've got a shell that supports it.

Comment: you can't imbricate backtick, and they are a readibility nightmare and use only by old-non-POSIX. While **`$()` is POSIX**, has better readibility and others advantages (see new references)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
case $(date +%U) in
    *[02468] ) VOLUME="A";;
    *) VOLUME="B";;
esac
```

Note also that spaces around `=` are not permitted.